# Ubuntu 16.04 occasional slow boot

Tags: boot, grub2

The problem:

My Ubuntu 16.04.06 LTS system boots very slow, sometimes. This seems to happen 1 out of 5 times when the power is cut off. Standard boot/reboot does not have this problem. 
But since it is a complete system the computer with Ubuntu will be shutdown by cutting off the power.

Testing:

*dmesg* did not show any gaps

*systemd-analyze*

```
Startup finished in 13.345s (firmware) + 16min 48.191s (loader) + 4.400s (kernel) + 8.632s (userspace) = 17min 14.569s
```

First time I checked *systemd-analyze*, the loader was at about 3 minutes.
Second time at 10 minutes. This output is the third time.

Since this only happens occasionally I don't even know where to start.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by disabling "Suspend to RAM" in the boot menu.